# SQL optimization : select distinct from one table

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

Suppose I have got a SQL like this

```
select  distinct CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_ORDER as ORDER
from MASTER_LIST 
where PROJECT_ID     = "ABCDD"
 order by   ORDER ASC
```

how can I optimize the performance of running this sql ?

Comment: Why does it need optimization?

Comment: When I use select distinct from two table joining , it runs slowly. Then I use where exists , it runs much faster.
So I am trying to find similar way to optimize it

Comment: Is there an index on PROJECT_ID?

Comment: Look at the execution plan, try to add indexes on columns used in group and where statements, look at new execution plan... remove / readd...

Comment: How to view the execution plan if Oracle SQL Developer is used

Comment: If you don't know how to do that, then drop whatever it is you're doing and **do not** touch a production database again until you learn how.

Comment: Read the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9010.htm#i2061796

Comment: And read the manual for SQL Developer: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35137_01/appdev.32/e35117/intro.htm#CHDEJJDB

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that with a group by would be better and more performant in most cases :

```
select  CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_ORDER as ORDER
from MASTER_LIST 
where PROJECT_ID     = "ABCDD"
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_ORDER
 order by   ORDER ASC
```

Comment: I guess Distinct and group by does the same process at the background and it does not really affect the performance

Comment: @AnandPhadke It depends on the backend database, usually is is better GROUP BY ...

Comment: You should be looking at the EXPLAIN PLAN for your answer - but afaik in ORACLE the optimizer should determine no difference between DISTINCT and GROUP BY.

Comment: An assertion of improved prerformance without a benchmark is no good to anyone.